# .java.MyFirebaseMessagingService where to find?

Tags: android

I want to handle pushing a push message according to the instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Got to the moment
[image]

But I don't have a MyFirebaseMessagingService file and I don't understand should I create it manually or should it appear when synchronizing dependencies?

Tell me, did I miss something in the instructions or what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class as `MyFirebaseMessagingService` and **extends** `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  //Called when a message is received.
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {//code goes here}

  //Called when a new token for the default Firebase project is generated.
  @Override
  public void onNewToken(String token) {//code goes here}

}
```

**NOTE:** There can only be one service in each app that receives FCM messages. If multiple are declared in the Manifest then the first one will be chosen.

You can read more on [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to understand should I create this file manually or it should have been when connecting the dependencies